# Stanford Javascript Crypto Library (SJCL): How to build sjcl.js and include the CBC mode

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I'm following the install here but running into trouble:

https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/version-0.8/README/INSTALL

```
npm install sjcl
pushd node_modules/sjcl; ./configure --without-all --with-aes --with-sha512 --with-cbc --with-codecHex && make; popd
```

This is the output from the configure and make above:

```
Enabled components:
  aes
  bitArray
  codecString
  codecHex
  sha512
  cbc

Compression: closure
cat core/sjcl.js core/aes.js core/bitArray.js core/codecString.js core/codecHex.js core/sha512.js core/cbc.js  > core.js
compress/compress_with_closure.sh core.js > core_closure.js
cp core_closure.js sjcl.js
```

It looks perfect, CBC was in the list.  Also, verify that it was included:

```
egrep sjcl.mode.cbc node_modules/sjcl/sjcl.js 
...{sjcl.mode.cbc={name:"cbc",encrypt:...
```

Great it was.  In my code, I can require in sjcl, but the sjcl.mode.cbc is undefined:

```
nodejs -e "sjcl=require('sjcl'); console.log(sjcl.mode);"
{}
```

This means the mode variable has nothing attached.  I would hope to see the cbc function attached there so I can use it.  How can I get a reference to and use cbc functions like `encrypt`?

Comment: The same thing happens under a recent `git clone https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl`

Answer (score 1):

you have to enable cbc manually in your code by calling

```
sjcl.beware["CBC mode is dangerous because it doesn't protect message integrity."]()
```

https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/issues/198#issuecomment-61111876

Comment: Or you can modify the cbc class so this is not needed.